# AJAX enabled WCF service in MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, wcf, webforms

So I can create a simple AJAX enabled WCF Service and consume it in Javascript in a basic WebForm as found in this example on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx).

Is it possible though to do this in ASP.NET MVC 3/4? The problem is there is no ScriptManager control obviously, which allows me to reference the service to be used in the javascript.

If it's not possible - how do I consume a WCF service inside javascript from ASP.NET MVC?

I cannot find any examples of this online either.. My google fu is off and I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your WCF service works with JSON and then use JQuery to call the service. This might help: http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/steps-to-call-wcf-service-using-jquery.html

Comment: thanks... works great.. also the code can be found on the original codeproject link for the same article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery